# Adding objects to two lists from a stream

Tags: java, if-statement, arraylist, foreach, java-stream

how can I add objects in two different lists from a stream in another way?

here's an example

```
ArrayList<String> someList = new ArrayList();
someList.add("123QWE");
someList.add("QWE123");
//...
ArrayList<String> list1 = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<String> list2 = new ArrayList<>();
someList.stream().forEach(string -> {
    if (Character.isDigit(string.charAt(0))
    {
        list1.add(string);
    }
    else
    {
        list2.add(string);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your updated question I would still go with a simple loop. Streams are great for some operations but their internals are quite complex. You can always call `Collections.sort()` on each list once the modifications to each list are complete.

This is not to say it can't be done with streams.  But imho, there is nothing gained by doing so.

```
ArrayList<Object> list1 = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<Object> list2 = new ArrayList<>();

for (String str : someList) {
     if (Character.isDigit(str.charAt(0)) {
         list1.add(str);
     } else {
         list2.add(str);
     }
}
Collections.sort(list1);
Collections.sort(list2);
```

But if you really want to use streams then here is one way.  It includes sorting (which you said you wanted in a comment) after you get done segregating the original list.

- define a `sortedList` collector to share for both streams. Not necessary but reduces code.
- the collector first collects them into a list.
- then sorts them.

```
Collector<String,?,List<String>>  sortedList = Collectors.collectingAndThen(
        Collectors.toList(),
        lst->{Collections.sort(lst); return lst;});
        
List<String> someList = List.of("B","3C","4E","A", "2B","C", "E", "1A");

List<String> list1 = someList.stream()
        .filter(str -> !Character.isDigit(str.charAt(0)))
        .collect(sortedList);

List<String> list2 = someList.stream()
        .filter(str -> Character.isDigit(str.charAt(0)))
        .collect(sortedList);

                
System.out.println(list1);
System.out.println(list2);
```

prints

```
[A, B, C, E]
[1A, 2B, 3C, 4E]
```

Comment: Actualy my idea is to split the source list into two different lists and then to sort each list.

Comment: But you don't indicate how `something` changes inside the loop.  It appears to be fixed.  Perhaps more information should be added to your question.  And `something` cannot change inside the `forEach loop` if it is local as it must  be effectively final.  Or an instance field of the enclosing class.

Comment: Yeah, sorry about that. I'll change my example

Answer (score 3):

Well, using Streams, you could also achieve this with a single stream:

```java
Map<Boolean, List<String>> partition = someList.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.partitioningBy(str -> Character.isDigit(str.charAt(0))));
```

Now

- `partition.get(true)` returns the list with string starting with digits;
- `partition.get(false)` returns the others.

Comment: Very nice.  If you add a `collectingAndThen` as the second argument to `partitioningBy` you can then sort the final list as indicated in the first comment to my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Use `stream.filter()` and `collect()` like this:

```java
list1 = someList.stream().filter(str -> Character.isDigit(str.charAt(0))).collect(Collectors.toList());
list2 = someList.stream().filter(str -> !Character.isDigit(str.charAt(0))).collect(Collectors.toList());
```